# Python - How to add a new column on SQL server & insert rows of lists

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, insert

I want to insert values to SQL Server from python. Here's my code:

```
for value in rows:
    cursor.execute ("""INSERT INTO Table ([ColumnOne]) VALUES (?)""", value)
cnxn.commit()
```

In `rows` , it contains lists (iteration) of rows, something like this:
row 1 contains of lists of float numbers

> 1.0
>   2.0
>   1.5
>   1.75

..... (in total of 1000 values in a row/column), 
And it goes the same with row2, row3, and so on. 
But, when I tried to run the code, I have this error

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but
>   1000 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Is there any way that I could do so the float values are not treated individually or to fix this problem?
I think maybe I should use `','.join` statement to make it as string? 
Considering I am not good at explaining and new to python, please correct me if i have some mistakes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attempt to insert multiple table rows in one query, you need to supply a list of values for each row.

For example, the following query would insert two rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO Table (ColumnOne) VALUES (1.0), (2.0);
```

So your python code needs to prepare the correct `VALUES` part of the query:

```py
for row in rows:
    values = ", ".join(("(?)",) * len(row))
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Table (ColumnOne) VALUES {values}", row)
```

Comment: Thank you, got it!